# Bootstrap accordion with arrow glyphs Changing bg color and arrow color after click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my accordion and I would like to:

after click in the arrow:

change the bg color of the panel from grey to red.
change the color of the arrow from grey to blue.

if not clicked  the panel the colour should back to the normal one: grey.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4x7y14wj/1/

css:

```
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: grey;         /* adjust as needed */
}
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">


  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- end container -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi add the following css code -- pure css way to achive

```
.panel-heading
{
  padding:0px;
}
.panel-title a
{
  padding:10px; 
  display:block;
}
.panel-title a[aria-expanded='true']
{
  background-color: red;
  color:#fff;
}
.panel-title a[aria-expanded='true']::after
{
  color:blue;
}
```

hope it works..

Comment: Ah, of course! `aria-expanded` - I think I had a brain fart when I wrote my answer! Very nice answer, Chandra!

Answer (score 1):

Think this is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/dennispreston/4x7y14wj/4/

**EDIT**

While this works, Chandra Shekhar's answer is a million times better!

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a id="toggle" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- end container -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
 .panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  /* symbol for "opening" panels */
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
  content: "\e114";
  /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
  float: right;
  /* adjust as needed */
  color: blue;
  /* adjust as needed */
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
  content: "\e080";
  /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
  color: grey;
}

.panel-heading {
  background: red!important;
}

.panel-heading.grey {
  background: #f5f5f5!important;
}
```

**jQuery**

If the panel heading has a child element with the `.collapsed` class, add `.grey` class to the panel heading. If not, remove it. Called on load and on click of toggle with delay so the `.collapsed` class is added before the script is run. This is a bit messy, I made it in a rush so any useful comments will be listened to and I will edit it with a tidier script.

```
$('.panel-heading:has(.collapsed)').addClass('grey');
$('.panel-heading:not(:has(.collapsed))').removeClass('grey');

$(".accordion-toggle").click(function() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('.panel-heading:has(.collapsed)').addClass('grey');
      $('.panel-heading:not(:has(.collapsed))').removeClass('grey');
    },
    10);
});
```